# Which desktop package am I actually using?

Tags: desktop-environments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find which desktop enviroment I am using?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125062/how-can-i-find-which-desktop-enviroment-i-am-using)

I'm a desktop user and boot straight into it. What's the best way to tell which desktop package I'm using (both kind and version), despite what would normally come with Ubuntu, and despite how it's configured or visually customized?  I assume this info is stored in a configuration file somewhere for viewing, or queryable in some programmatic manner.

Comment: Post a screen shot and someone will tell you. Print Screen key should work.

Comment: @wojox: Interesting solution but I'm looking for something more generic. Not every user who comes across this question and wants to know their desktop should have to post a screen shot. They should be able to follow a prescribed solution according to the question.

Comment: Here's a pretty generic command that works if the user has sudoers access: `sudo grep "Starting session" /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log
`

Comment: [Possible duplicate here](http://askubuntu.com/q/125062/12864). It's more recent and has a simple, accepted answer.

Comment: $ ps aux | grep gnome-session

Comment: $ gnome-shell --version results in: 
GNOME Shell 3.18.5

Answer (score 2):

If you go to System > Administration > System Monitor, enter you password when prompted and then select the System tab, you will see the details of your current install, eg:

```
Ubuntu
Release 10.10 (maverick)
Kernel Linux 2.6.35-28-generic
GNOME 2.32.0
```

Where, in this case, the desktop environment is Gnome 2.32.0

Comment: The user may have to find the 'System Monitor' tool in their version of the desktop, if it's not under that specific path.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu you can use following commands:

- **echo $DESKTOP_SESSION**: This command return ubuntu when you are using Unity and ubuntu-2d when you are using Unity 2D and ...

or

- **sudo grep "Starting session" /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log**: Because of last version of Ubuntu use lightdm as display manager you can see **last line** of the lightdm.log file.

When you find out which desktop environment you are using, you can go to a package manager program like "synaptic" and check what is your desktop environment version.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the following commands in the terminal

```
lsb_release -a
uname -a
cat /proc/version
```

Comment: Those exact commands don't provide me any info about the desktop being used, only about the Ubuntu distribution.  For example, there's no mention of Gnome 2.32.1 and in my circumstance that's the currently installed/running desktop.

Comment: Here's the actual output of all the commands mentioned in your original suggestion: `john@ubuntu:/$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 11.04
Release: 11.04
Codename: natty
john@ubuntu:/$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 2.6.38-8-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 03:31:24 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
john@ubuntu:/$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.38-8-generic (buildd@allspice) (gcc version 4.5.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu3) ) #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 03:31:24 UTC 2011
`

Answer (score 0):

Install the [sysinfo [image: Install sysinfo]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/sysinfo) application from Ubuntu Software Center. It can give all the information you need.