# How can I find which desktop enviroment I am using?

Tags: command-line, desktop-environments

as the title:

How can I find which **desktop environment** I am using?

I want to accomplish this using command line.

Comment: this topic is also discussed [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/72549/determine-what-window-manager-is-running)

Comment: If you are looking for a way to identify xubuntu vs lubuntu vs edubuntu etc. and your OSes were installed via CD, the following might help: `grep cdrom: /etc/apt/sources.list | sed -n '1s|.*deb cdrom:\[\([^ ]* *[^ ]*\).*|\1|p'`

Comment: @Luis Alvarado Is desktop environment and window manager are same (because marked as duplicate)?

Comment: @Pandya no, the values will be different, but on the duplicate it shows how to grab the value for both (And other examples for WM and DE).

Comment: @Lucio, not sure why this question was erroneously marked as a duplicate of a completely different question. Please read this question first and remove the duplicate question marker: https://askubuntu.com/questions/18078/what-is-the-difference-between-a-desktop-environment-and-a-window-manager

Comment: Just because the so called "original" contains an answer with solution to this question, does not mean that this question is a duplicate. The desktop environment and window manager are not the same things. These are different questions. The justification for closing this question is, quite simply, wrong, and the decision must be reversed.

Comment: @Lucio I've tried to elaborate on your edits to finally get the attention of someone with the authority to reverse the marking-as-duplicate. If this doesn't work then there is something seriously wrong with StackExchange! ( :

Comment: MRule, the duplicate answer also tells how to find the desktop environment, and the title has been edited to reflect this.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

And you can try `$DESKTOP_SESSION` for the DE.

Comment: when I type `$ echo $DESKTOP_SESSION`, it show: `ubuntu` why this?

Comment: Desktop session != Window manager

Comment: My second problem is about DE (desktop environment), which you answered. I think the answer should be `gnome`, but it is `ubuntu`, why?

Comment: Ubuntu is the name of the gnome 3+unity DE.

Comment: I get nothing, using `Lubuntu 16.4` with `lxde`

Comment: I still get nothing, using `Lubuntu 20.4` with `lxqt`

Comment: `echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`

Comment: Really `$DESKTOP_SESSION` returns the `Window Manager` (that's why it returns `Ubuntu`), for the original question the correct answer is `$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` as indicated in the previous comment

Comment: `$ echo $DESKTOP_SESSION` gives me nothing (Ubuntu 22).

Answer (score 72):

This command seems to be useful:

```
ls /usr/bin/*session
```

- in GNOME returns `/usr/bin/gnome-session` (and more)
- in MATE returns `/usr/bin/mate-session` (and more)
- in LXDE returns `/usr/bin/lxsession` (and more)
- in JWM returns `/usr/bin/icewm-session` (should be jwm-session, not?!)

Comment: I got /usr/bin/ck-launch-session  /usr/bin/ck-xinit-session  /usr/bin/gnome-session. So what? I'm using CentOS.

Comment: This is the only simple answer that worked for me. `gnome-session`

Comment: /usr/bin/dbus-run-session   which one is this?

Comment: In the Raspberry Pi 2, we have a choice of 3 window sessions: lx and openbox.  As I commented earlier, echo $DESKTOP_SESSION ==> LXDE-pi (installation value) is a definitive indicator for RPI2.

Comment: This only shows which DE's you have installed, not which is currently used.

Comment: For Xfce (e.g. on Xubuntu) you'll find `/usr/bin/xfce4-session` existing.

Comment: in KDE returns `/usr/bin/plasma_session`, sort of

Answer (score 29):

I've tested the best tools I've found with:

**a** - **GNOME** under Linux Mint installed
**b** - **GNOME** under Linux Mint Live USB
**c** - **MATE** under Linux Mint
**d** - **LXDE** under Lubuntu
**e** - **JWM** under Puppy Linux (JWM is not a desktop environment but a stacking window manager).
**f** - **XFCE** under Debian Buster

#### Results

- `env | grep DESKTOP_SESSION=` (so-so)

  ```
  a & b - DESKTOP_SESSION=gnome
  c - DESKTOP_SESSION=default.desktop
  d - DESKTOP_SESSION=Lubuntu
  e - Nothing
  f - DESKTOP_SESSION=xfce
  ```
- `echo $GDMSESSION` (so-so)

  ```
  a & b - gnome
  c - Nothing
  d - Lubuntu
  e - Nothing
  f - xfce
  ```
- `pgrep -l "gnome|kde|mate|cinnamon|lxde|xfce|jwm"` or `ps -A | egrep -i "gnome|kde|mate|cinnamon|lxde|xfce|jwm"` (well, but not perfect)

  ```
  a & b - OK
  c - OK
  d - WRONG
  e - Nothing & OK
  f - OK
  ```
- `HardInfo` (very well, but not perfect)

  ```
  a - Nothing
  b - GNOME 2.32.0
  c - MATE
  d - LXDE (Lubuntu)
  e - Unknown (Window Manager: JWM)
  f - XFCE
  ```

#### Conclusion

A combination of `HardInfo` and the command `ps -A | egrep -i "gnome|kde|mate|cinnamon|lxde|xfce|jwm"` probably will give the desired answer.

Comment: Adding case f (Raspberry Pi 2 running 2016-05-27 Jessie): echo $DESKTOP_SESSION ==> LXDE-pi which says it all.

Comment: What do mean my "HardInfo" ? Can you please explain that

Comment: @AviMehenwal [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/281459/226416) explains it.

Comment: With gnome under Debian 8.11 `DESKTOP_SESSION=default` so for me [the answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/281554/613676) from @Nadew above worked

Comment: in my case, I need to know if i am using unity or lxde, and after testing many commands, I found that `env | grep XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` says what i need.

Comment: wanted to note a caveat for newbies / folks scripting DE detection logic: if you plan on using ps/prgep, then you will likely need a more complex pattern than suggested above as there are many processes that will give false positives if you simply use the de name by itself. On my system, the only DE is Cinnamon. This comes with `gnome-terminal` as terminal app. I also have kmag installed. Running ps/pgrep I get false positives for `kdevtmpfs` and `gnome-keyring-daemon` even tho gnome & kde are not installed.

Comment: ^ so for detecting in script, I would recommend exhausting env variables (e.g. DESKTOP_SESSION / XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP / GDMSESSION), then possibly trying to detect based on either session binaries (e.g. `ls -acl /usr/bin/*session`) or presence of file managers (e.g. `test 1 == $(which nemo 2>/dev/null|wc -l)` ). Other options not listed in the older answer might also be useful such as : `sudo grep -i session /var/lib/AccountsService/users/$USER` or `grep PREFERRED /etc/sysconfig/desktop` but I am not sure how consistently those are used across distros

Comment: Do consider `lxqt` as a desktop env.

Answer (score 18):

For the window manager [you can use](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1623820):

```
sudo apt-get install wmctrl
wmctrl -m | grep "Name:" | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: You can all about your system by just installing - Sysinfo. Search for it on USC.

Comment: Sysinfo doesn't tell you which window manager you're using.  It only tells you which version of xorg you're running -- at least on my system.

Comment: This is the only answer that seems not only to work but work on all systems and provide output that is concise and incisive -- and I am _not_ talking about "Curious Apprentice"'s answer.  Curious Apprentice's "answer" should be ignored as it detracts from the only real answer.

Comment: I would not consider the answer here as appropriate as the `window manager` is a own issue compared to the `desktop env`, please correct if I am wrong.

Answer (score 9):

In a terminal or console, you can run:

```
pgrep -l "gnome|kde|mate|cinnamon"
```

or

```
ps -A | egrep -i "gnome|kde|mate|cinnamon"
```

The item that appears in more lines should be the answer

Comment: I'm getting only `31 kdevtmpfs`, `2026 gnome-keyring-d`, `2201 polkit-gnome-au`, and I'm on xfce.

Comment: same here. added xfce to the regex at least shows something useful, but a lot of heuristics would be required to determine with any certainty what DE you're using

Answer (score 1):

You can run HardInfo. It's ready by default at least in Linux Mint; or you could install it (from Synaptic, ...).

You can run it a) from the main menu > Search box > hardinfo, or b) from the main menu > All applications > System Tools or Administration > System Information, or c) from the main menu > All applications > All > System Information, or d) from a terminal or console > hardinfo > Enter, or e) from the Run Application dialog (Alt+F2) > hardinfo > Enter.

Once HardInfo opens you just need to need to click on the "Operating System" item and look to the "Desktop Environment" line.

Nowadays, apart from GNOME and KDE, you could find MATE, Cinnamon, ...

Comment: UniMous asked for command line option. He can not click from there. Unless this program can give a file output as report it does not useful for him.

Comment: Find out how HardInfo gets the Desktop Environment and maybe you can find a way to do the same via the command line.

Comment: You can install hardinfo with `sudo apt-get install hardinfo` on debian. It identified my desktop environment as _XFCE 4_.

Comment: There's no mention of the DE in 18.04