# Basic question on ubuntu desktop /interface

Tags: interface

I need lil clarity , I am sort of lil new to ubuntu [ a week old :)]. I am exploring the OS and really finding it awesome . Meanwhile, I did come up with some basic doubts which needs clarity . I would be thankful to any body who can give me clarity.

### Just some info before my question

1. I know ubuntu comes with server as well as with desktop versions
2. I installed the ubuntu desktop version 15.04 version
3. While, I was going through few youtube videos on ubuntu, I came across people referring other desktops on ubuntu like cinnamon , lxde , unity , etc

### My questions

1. So my confusion started from here, Are they referring to an interface as a desktop ?
2. Ubuntu /linux though they are operating system by themself.Do they still have the ability to have different desktops on top of them?
3. Is it something like a skin, i can choose different versions?
4. what command should i use to find what desktop i have on top of my ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes
2. Yes
3. Not like a skin, but yes you can choose different versions
4. Not sure, but by default Ubuntu 15.04 comes with Unity, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things I wanted to address:

- Ubuntu desktop and server versions are pretty much the same. The difference is that server comes with additional software for "serious" tasks and no graphic interface - only command line.
- All *nix systems in general started out as command-line. There was no GUI back when Unix was created by Ken Thompson in 1969. Any graphic interface on *nix systems relies on a graphical server. Think of it as a software layer - you can have that software or not, the system still works without it and can perform necessary tasks. Now, back when *nix systems started getting graphics, computers weren't that powerful, so you would have to login in console, and then type `startx` to get that graphical layer started (namely, you would start the X server. There's other graphical servers nowadays). That in turn would start your *window manager* - the program that controls how your windows will look and feel. Now, if on one computer (even on the same computer but for different users) we have `unity` and on another `openbox` as default manager - we're gonna get different look and different behavior of the GUI programs. But they still are started with X graphical server, and still running on Ubuntu. In a sense they are like a skin, but a skin that comes with varying features and ability to customize. For instance, `motif` window manager cannot be tweaked that much (at least I have not heard of it ), but `cinnamon` can be - there's tons of skins, you can place the panel on any four sides of the window, etc.
- Nowadays there's another way things work - you have instance of X server running to show you the login screen (aka the greeter or desktop manager ). Desktop manager does the same job as `startx`. Only instead of two steps (login and run `startx` ) you just do one step in this case.
- I've looked through [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/125062/295286)  and IMHO the only method that works across the board with `wmctrl -m`. It worked in both `openbox` and `gnome` sessions, which I have open right now on tty1 and tty7. You can also try to trace the output of `pstree` to find out what session you have running, but that will be a bit confusing if you have multiple sessions open like I do. I have `openbox` started with `startx` so it's the parent process of that, but for `gnome` parent process is `lightdm` greeter.