# How do I find which DE is running on 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, server, ssh, desktop-environments

I'm logged into an Ubuntu 14.04 server remotely with `ssh`. I'm trying to find out which Desktop Environment is running.  When I do the following, nothing happens:

```
admin@server:~$ echo $DESKTOP_SESSION
admin@server:~$ echo $XDG_CURRENT_SESSION
admin@server:~$
```

I know for a fact that there is a desktop running on the server. I saw it this morning, but now I'm 5 miles away.

Comment: I believe that is what you want.

Comment: To be clear, the question of the dupe target ostensibly mentions "window manager" but there are many answers there that actually check for desktop environments.

Comment: "I know for a fact that there is a desktop running on the server" <<< How do you know that? Maybe it's just a wm with various embellishments giving the impression that there's a desktop environment.

Comment: - why would there be a desktop on a server?

Comment: `ls /usr/bin/*session` would be what I would use. see http://askubuntu.com/questions/125062/how-can-i-find-which-desktop-enviroment-i-am-using