# How do I determine which is the current user's DE through CLI within SSH or Cron?

Tags: command-line, ssh, cron, desktop-environments, tty

Let's assume we have a computer with Ubuntu Desktop installed on it. There are a few desktop environments (DE) installed such as: Unity, Gnome, KDE, XFCE, Mate, etc.

Also few users have their accounts and they regularly using the computer. Each user could change its DE according to its free will :)

**How to determinate which is the current user's desktop environment, for certain user, through CLI within limited environment?**

This question could be fragmented in this way:

- In which file is stored this information?
- What is the best way to read it through a script executed within an limited environment such as `ssh` session or `cron`?
- How to read this information for random user?
- I'm finding for one line command solution if it is possible.

Comment: The proposed [`dename.sh`](https://github.com/alexeevdv/dename) script doesn't recognize my Lubuntu 16.04 LXDE correctly, it says “KDE 4.14.16” instead probably because I have a bunch of KDE programs installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I've managed to create script, that has 100% success with several dozen attempts within 13 different desktop environments.

The script analysis the content of each `/proc/$PID/envion` file of the subject user and determine which is its current desktop environment.

```bsh
$ cat ~/find-DE.bash

#!/bin/bash

# Determinate the subject user - $USR
if [ "$1" == "simple" ]; then
                USR="$(id -u)"
                OUTPUT="simple"
elif [ -z "${1}" ]; then
                USR="$(id -u)"
                OUTPUT="$2"
else
                USR="$1"
                OUTPUT="$2"
fi

[ "$USR" == "$(id -u)" ] && SUDO="" || SUDO="sudo"

# Get the most frequent value of any array - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43440769/6543935
get_frequent(){
    awk 'BEGIN{FS=" "} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}' | \
    awk '
      {
          n=++hsh[$1]
          if(n>max_occ){
             max_occ=n
             what=$1
          }else if(n==max_occ){
             if(what>$1)
                 what=$1
          }
      }
      END { print what }
    '
}

# Get the numbers of all $USR's processes
PS=`pgrep -U "${USR}"`

# Get the values of $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP, $GDMSESSION, $DESKTOP_SESSION from each "/proc/$ProcessNumber/environ" file
for PN in $PS; do
        XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP+=$($SUDO sed -zne 's/^XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=//p' "/proc/$PN/environ" 2>/dev/null; echo " ")
        GDMSESSION+=$($SUDO sed -zne 's/^GDMSESSION=//p' "/proc/$PN/environ" 2>/dev/null; echo " ")
        DESKTOP_SESSION+=$($SUDO sed -zne 's/^DESKTOP_SESSION=//p' "/proc/$PN/environ" 2>/dev/null; echo " ")
done

# Get the most frequent name of any desctop environment
# This is a way to find the current DE when it is changed a little bit ago
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=$(echo -e ${XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP[@]} | get_frequent)
GDMSESSION=$(echo -e ${GDMSESSION[@]} | get_frequent)
DESKTOP_SESSION=$(echo -e ${DESKTOP_SESSION[@]} | get_frequent)

# Print the output values
if [ "$OUTPUT" == "simple" ]; then
        echo "${XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP[@],,}" | sed 's/\-.*//'
else
        echo "user: $(id -n -u $USR)"
        echo "uid:  $USR"
        echo "XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP: ${XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP[@]^}"
        echo "GDMSESSION:          ${GDMSESSION[@]^}"
        echo "DESKTOP_SESSION:     ${DESKTOP_SESSION[@]^}"
fi
```

Usage:

```bsh
$ ~/find-DE.bash
user: spas
uid:  1000
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP: GNOME-Classic:GNOME
GDMSESSION:          Gnome-classic
DESKTOP_SESSION:     Gnome-classic

$ ~/find-DE.bash simple
gnome

$ ~/find-DE.bash 1001
user: guest
uid:  1001
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP: Unity
GDMSESSION:          Ubuntu
DESKTOP_SESSION:     Ubuntu

$ time ~/find-DE.bash 1001 simple
unity

real    0m1.587s
user    0m0.536s
sys     0m0.400s
```

More results:

```bsh
#1
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP: Unity
GDMSESSION:          Ubuntu
DESKTOP_SESSION:     Ubuntu

#2
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP: GNOME
GDMSESSION:          Gnome
DESKTOP_SESSION:     Gnome

#3
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP: GNOME-Classic:GNOME
GDMSESSION:          Gnome-classic
DESKTOP_SESSION:     Gnome-classic

#4
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP: LXDE
GDMSESSION:          LXDE
DESKTOP_SESSION:     LXDE

#5
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP: LXDE
GDMSESSION:          Lubuntu
DESKTOP_SESSION:     Lubuntu

#6
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP: LXDE
GDMSESSION:          Lubuntu-Netbook
DESKTOP_SESSION:     Lubuntu-Netbook

#7
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP: GNOME
GDMSESSION:          Openbox
DESKTOP_SESSION:     Openbox

#8
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP: KDE
GDMSESSION:          Plasma
DESKTOP_SESSION:     Plasma

#9
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP: XFCE
GDMSESSION:          Xfce
DESKTOP_SESSION:     Xfce

#10
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP: XFCE
GDMSESSION:          Xubuntu
DESKTOP_SESSION:     Xubuntu

#11
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP: X-Cinnamon
GDMSESSION:          Cinnamon
DESKTOP_SESSION:     Cinnamon

#12
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP: X-Cinnamon
GDMSESSION:          Cinnamon2d
DESKTOP_SESSION:     Cinnamon2d

#13
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP: MATE
GDMSESSION:          Mate
DESKTOP_SESSION:     Mate
```

:)

Comment: XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP: LXDE | GDMSESSION: Lubuntu | DESKTOP_SESSION: Lubuntu – Congratulations! For the use in a script IMHO it should output just “lxde” though. Or maybe make it available via options?

Comment: I just found https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/394763/246819 – maybe `loginctl` can be of use here?

Comment: Hi, @dessert, thank you for this suggestion. Next week I will read about the command `loginctl`. I'm still working on my idea, but unfortunately few days ago I accidentally deleted the script, right then when I finished it :-) So I ran a GitHub project to prevent future silly mistakes as this. Now [the new script](https://github.com/pa4080/cron-gui-launcher/blob/master/cron-gui-launcher.bash) is finished, it become lighter than the previous version, but the documentation and the tests are still in progress. Here is a demo of the previous version:

Comment: [THE DEMO](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLO24trCW6Y8evkphLwjzU_AdrznkarVS9)

Comment: This reply deserves about 100 more upvotes.  This is a daunting task to accomplish across all DEs. Anyway... I'm testing on `Fedora 27` and the desktop is running as a dedicated user... `gdm`, so the exports aren't found.

Comment: ... nevermind, the script works fine, my similar technique did not.

Comment: Hi, @tresf, I haven't used Fedora, but in Ubuntu the window manager lightdm/gdm/etc. is owner of the desktop session while there is not any logged-in user. Whatever I think this project of mine could be interesting for you: https://github.com/pa4080/cron-gui-launcher

Comment: @pa4080 that's a nice project.  I was wonder if any of this logic made it to GitHub.  I feel the project is more than just `cron`.  This logic is equally helpful for a desktop installer to launch the software as a current user.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $DESKTOP_SESSION
```

shows the currently used desktop environment.

Find other good approaches here:

- [How can I find which desktop enviroment I am using?](https://askubuntu.com/a/281535/507051)
- [How to detect the desktop environment in a bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116539/how-to-detect-the-desktop-environment-in-a-bash-script)
- [How to return the currently active user/session on a Linux desktop?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/394709/how-to-return-the-currently-active-user-session-on-a-linux-desktop/394763)