# Understanding my ubuntu desktop appearance

Tags: gnome, lightdm, gdm

This is a total newbie question, but I can't seem to figure out how my Ubuntu (16.0.4) desktop appearance works. I can't even understand the terminology so I don't know what to search for.

I know there is something called `Gnome` and `KDE`, also after installing gnome desktop as in '[How to change from GDM to LightDM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139491/how-to-change-from-gdm-to-lightdm)' I learned that Gnome can be `GDM` or `LightDM`.

Both modes look completely different from what I have on Centos and Redhat machines (which according to [How can I find which desktop enviroment I am using?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125062/how-can-i-find-which-desktop-enviroment-i-am-using) is also `Gnome`). The latter is what I actually want.

I don't want to waste helpers time, so if someone can just explain the terms/hierarchy in high level so I can look it up.

And if someone feels extra generous might help me achieve what I actually want which is a desktop like I have on my RedHat machine (last image below). Thanks.

**Here is what I get when setting GDM3:**

[image]

**Here is what I get when setting LightDM (looks exactly the same, only without login screen):**

[image]

**On my home laptop there is some purple desktop where the menu is on the side and has a 'whirlpool' button on top... (I don't remember the name)**

**Here is what I would like to have:**

[image]

Comment: `gdm` and `lightdm` are display managers, more or less login managers. Both gdm and lightdm allow you to chose which desktop environment will be run after the login (Gnome, kde, xfce, lxde).

Comment: Form the picture you posted, looks like you want Gnome2. Big difference between Gnome2 and Gnome3. You need not waste time mucking with display manager settings - simply install the entire desktop environment properly using apt, then reboot...or reinstall the one you want to avoid confusion when you have more than one Display Environment installed at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to use Ubuntu MATE I think. It looks like this:

[image]

Download it here: [https://ubuntu-mate.org](https://ubuntu-mate.org/)

Direct download link: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-mate/releases/16.04.4/release/ubuntu-mate-16.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso

If you want it to look like in the image above you should download **Ubuntu MATE 16.04**. There has been some changes to the GUI in 18.04.

Comment: Thanks, I have installed mate 1.14 but still getting the same appearance as before, even after reboot. Any idea how to switch to mate?

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu MATE? Did you install it from scratch using the ISO or did you install it via APT?

Comment: I would suggest you download this image http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-mate/releases/16.04.4/release/ubuntu-mate-16.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso and reinstall your machine with that image.

Comment: I installed it from package. I am now trying to install it clean from ISO with the link you sent. So far looks good no problems.

Comment: Nice to hear. No problem :)